# How to add ref to element using portal in react?

Tags: reactjs

i want to add ref to element using createPortal.

Below is what i am trying to do

```
export default class Modal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.element_ref = React.createRef();
        this.element = document.createElement('div');
        this.element.className = 'modal_class';
    }

    render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        this.props.children,
        this.element
    );
}
```

The question is how can i add a ref in this case named "this.element_ref" to this.element?

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: why do you need ref here? this.element is already dom node.

Comment: hmm i need to add a ref to it to access it from other component

Comment: how will you pass ref to other component? you can pass same this.element to other component.

Comment: i want to access it in parent component

Comment: you can pass setElement function from parent to children and then on componentDidMount you can set this.element to parent component.